# Probability of disease in a population through a Binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

> Given that 20% of a population has a certain disease, calculate the probability that at least 400 people will have this disease among 1300 people chosen at random from the population.

I tried approximating a Binomial distribution through a Poisson distribution. 1300 * 0,2 = 260.

$$ 1 - \sum_{x = 0}^{399}p(x;260) = 1 - \sum_{x = 0}^{399}\frac{e^{-260} * 260^{x}}{x!} $$

However this number is too far away from reality. Am I using the wrong method here?

Comment: I cannot find a mistake. Have you tried normal approximation (in order to compare)?

Comment: I have calculated both ways ( Poisson distribution and the actual Binomial distribution ) but I'm finding it hard to believe in the results.

Comment: If 20% of people are sick, I wouldn't expect a result on the $1 - 10^{-20}$ range. Unless I'm missing something here.